# Why can I only select Webcam0 on AVD / Xamarin emulator?

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.android, android-virtual-device

I have 2 virtual webcams installed on my PC (Actually 3, also a hardware webcam, which is disabled for now.

Both of them show up in the device manager:
[image: Device manager]

However, I cannot get this to work with AVD or Xamarin emulators. I need to test a back and a front webcam, however selecting webcam0 on both will not work. I tried webcam1, webcam<1>, but then it will simply not show any webcams.

[image: Device setup]

Is there any way to get 2 camera's working? I need Android 11, so Genymotion is not an option...

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it!

Used manycam to create a second virtual camera, then started the emulator with -camera-front webcam1 -camera-back webcam2

Now both my camera's are showing. Which is awesome!